# React - How I can show submitted form records into another component in format of <li>?

Tags: reactjs

I started learning React few weeks back and wanted to create small application. User will enter his details through form and his records will visible into table. But after record form fields details, I'm not able to show records into table, can someone help me.

I have 3 components ->

- Main component = ShowFormRecords.jsx
- Sub component = ShowTable.jsx
- Sub component = ShowForm.jsx

In ShowForm.jsx I am able to record form fields value through this.onSubmit function in console.log(this.state);

Now how I can show recorded form details into another sub component ShowTable.jsx. I learned something about dynamic props can communicate one component to another component, but not able to implement here as per my requirement.

**Component: ShowFormRecords.jsx**

```
// Let's import React
import React from "react";

// Import custom component
import ShowTable from "./showformrecords/ShowTable.jsx";
import ShowForm from "./showformrecords/ShowForm.jsx";

// Let's create component [[ShowFormRecords]]
class ShowFormRecords extends React.Component{

    render(){
        return(
            <div className="row">

                <div className="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12">
                    <h3> View Customer Records </h3>
                </div>

                <div className="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-8 col-xl-8">
                    <ShowTable />
                </div>

                <div className="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
                    <ShowForm />
                </div>                        

            </div>
        );
    }
}

// Let's render ReactDOM
export default ShowFormRecords;
```

**ShowTable.jsx**

```
// Let's import React
import React from "react";

// Let's create component [[ShowTable]]
class ShowTable extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(

            <div>

                <table className="table table-responsive">
                    <thead className="thead-inverse">
                        <tr>
                            <th>#</th>
                            <th>First Name</th>
                            <th>Last Name</th>
                            <th>Phone No.</th>
                            <th>Issue</th>
                            <th>Action</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="row"> <input type="checkbox" className="form-check-input" /> </th>
                            <td>Mark</td>
                            <td>Otto</td>
                            <td>0000000000</td>
                            <td>My pc is not working</td>
                            <td><button type="button" className="btn btn-danger">Delete</button></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table> 
            </div>
        );
    }
}

// Let's render ReactDOM
export default ShowTable;
```

**ShowForm.jsx**

```
// Let's import React
import React from "react";

// Let's create component [[ShowForm]]
class ShowForm extends React.Component{

    // create constructor function for AddCustomer component - to init 
    constructor(props){

        // call super, so constructor function can connect with AddCustomer component - to init super component
        super(props);

            // Use state add object with their property and value
            this.state = {                
                firstName : "",
                lastName : "",
                phoneNo : "",
                issue : "",    
            }  

        // Creat custom change function
        this.change = e =>{
            this.setState({
                [e.target.name]: e.target.value
            });
        };

        this.onSubmit = e =>{
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log(this.state);


            // clear form fields after click on submit button, use setState for setting value 
            this.setState({
                firstName : "",
                lastName : "",
                phoneNo : "",
                issue : "",
            })
        }

    } // close constructor function





    render(){
        return(

            <form onSubmit={e => this.onSubmit(e)}>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label htmlFor="fname">First name</label>
                    <input 
                        type="text"  
                        className="form-control" 
                        id="fname" 
                        placeholder="First name"    
                        name = "firstName"                    
                        value={this.state.firstName}
                        onChange = { e => this.change(e) }
                        // onChange={e => this.setState({firstName: e.target.value})}
                        />
                        {/* call setState for change firstName value */}
                </div>

                <div className="form-group">
                    <label htmlFor="lname">Last name</label>
                    <input 
                        type="text"  
                        className="form-control" 
                        id="lname" 
                        placeholder="Last name"
                        name="lastName"
                        value={this.state.lastName}    
                        onChange = { e => this.change(e) }                          
                        // onChange={e => this.setState({lastName: e.target.value})}
                        />
                        {/* call setState for change lastName value */}
                </div>

                <div className="form-group">
                    <label htmlFor="phone">Phone no.</label>
                    <input 
                        type="text" 
                        className="form-control" 
                        id="phone" 
                        placeholder="Phone no."
                        name="phoneNo"
                        value={this.state.phoneNo}   
                        onChange = { e => this.change(e) }
                        // onChange={e => this.setState({phoneNo: e.target.value})}
                        />
                        {/* call setState for change phoneNo value */}
                </div>

                <div className="form-group">
                    <label htmlFor="issue">Issue</label>
                    <textarea  
                        className="form-control" 
                        id="issue" 
                        rows="3"
                        name="issue"
                        value={this.state.issue}
                        onChange = { e => this.change(e) }
                        // onChange={e => this.setState({issue: e.target.value})}
                        >
                        {/* call setState for change issue value */}

                    </textarea>
                </div>

                <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary"> Submit </button>



            </form>

        );
    }
}

// Let's render ReactDOM
export default ShowForm;
```

Answer (score 0):

Move your state from your `ShowForm` component up into your `ShowFormRecords` components.  Then pass the state from the `ShowFormRecords` component into both your `ShowTable` and `ShowForm` component.  By doing so, you can update your state in the `ShowForm` component then render that data on your `ShowTable` component.

Comment: Think of your `ShowFormRecords` as a container component that handles your data and the 2 sub-components as presentational components where you present the data to your user.